# Design dilemma: If e-mail address already used, send e-mail "e-mail address already registered", but can't because can't add duplicate to table

Tags: mysql, security, language-agnostic, registration, confirmation-email

A registration form asks for  **username** and **e-mail address**. After the data passes validation it's added to the `accounts` table. It stores data such as username, password and e-mail address. If the username has already been taken the user will be notified and no data will be added to the table. It was seen as a [security issue](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36884/obtaining-e-mail-address-at-registration) if the user was immediately notified that the e-mail address was already in the table. The suggested solution to this was to always send a verification e-mail and if the entered username already existed the e-mail would say "*this e-mail address has already been used*" (and no activation link would be given of course).

**The problem** is that as it works now, if the `INSERT` query fails to insert the data into the table the message "Username taken" is shown. This may be wrong because the e-mail address is set to unique in the table so the query fails if the same e-mail address is entered. I can no longer send out a verification e-mail saying "*this e-mail address has already been used*" because there is no record in the table containing said e-mail address.

How can I redesign the system so it works?

I'm using MySQL and the table `accounts` has the primary key `username` unique key `e-mail` and the attributes `password` and `activation`.

```
if(mysqli_stmt_execute($createAccount))
    echo 'Username available!';
else
    echo 'Username unavailable!';
```

In SQL is there some way to check to see why the query couldn't be inserted into the table? For example could it tell which attribute had a duplicate value?

Please let me know if my question is unclear.

Comment: Discussion [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35161/discussion-between-celeritas-and-robert-harvey).

Answer (score 1):

Run a SELECT query first to identify duplicates.  If no duplicates are found, then you can perform your INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

*if* you want the DB to perform the required check *while inserting* the data *and* you want to be able to distinguish between a failed attempt to add an email and a failed attempt to add a username, the most straightforward solution is to have both an `email` table and an `username`table. Your actual `account` table would just keep foreign key to those two tables. Here is an example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a24df:

```
CREATE TABLE username (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, value CHAR(80) UNIQUE NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE email (id  INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, value CHAR(80) UNIQUE NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE account(id  INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                     username_id  INT NOT NULL,
                     email_id INT NOT NULL,
                     FOREIGN KEY (username_id) REFERENCES username(id),
                     FOREIGN KEY (email_id) REFERENCES email(id) );
```

Adding a new user will be now performed as several steps *in a transaction*. You will now be able to know which step failed if any. And being in a transaction, that will conserve the atomicity of the account creation:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO email(value) VALUES ("x@y.com");
INSERT INTO username(value) VALUES ("Sylvain");

-- you could obtain the ID programmatically by "last_insert_id"-like function 
INSERT INTO account(username_id, email_id) VALUES (1,1); 
COMMIT;
```

And querying username and email for a given account will now require a join:

```
SELECT username.value AS username, email.value AS email 
FROM username JOIN account ON username.id = account.username_id
JOIN email ON email.id = account.email_id
WHERE account.id = 1;
```

I wouldn't say this is necessary the best solution but it works as you wish, I think.