# Inserting Persons with IDs in one query?

Tags: mysql, last-insert-id

I need to add data to a MySQL database like that:

`Person:
pId, nameId, titleId, age`

`Name:
nameId, name`

`Title:
titleId, title`

I don't want to have any names or title more then once in the db so I didn't see a solution with `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

My approach looks like that:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Name(name) VALUES ("Peter");
INSERT IGNORE INTO Title(title) VALUES ("Astronaut");
INSERT INTO Person(nameId, titleId, age) VALUES ((SELECT nameId FROM Name WHERE name = "Peter"), (SELECT nameId FROM Name WHERE name = "Astronaut"), 33);
```

But I guess that's a quite dirty approach!?
If possible I want to add multiple persons with one query and without having anything more then one times in db.
Is this possible in a nice way? Thanks!

Comment: why is the column 'name' and 'title' not in one table ? Then using last_insert_id() would be way easier.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Design dielema; If e-mail address already used send email "e-mail address already regsitered" but can't because can't add duplicate to table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154031/design-dielema-if-e-mail-address-already-used-send-email-e-mail-address-alread)

Comment: @KarelG because then if I would add "Peter", "Astronaut2" and "Peter", "Astronaut3" and "Peter", "Astronaut4" for example I would always add "Peter" to db. I want to store "Peter" just one times in the db and having the id as alias for all other peters afterwards. Or isn't that right? I though you should save as much space as possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put title and name as two columns of your table and then:

- set one `UNIQUE` index on each column if you don"t want to have two titles or two names identical in the DB
- *or* set an `UNIQUE` index on `(title,name)` if you don't want to have two entries having both the same name *and* the same title.

---

If you *really* want to have separate tables, you could do as you suggested in your post, but wrapping all your insert statements in a `TRANSACTION` to allow rollback if you detect a duplicate somewhere.

See [Design dilemma: If e-mail address already used, send e-mail "e-mail address already registered", but can't because can't add duplicate to table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154031/design-dielema-if-e-mail-address-already-used-send-email-e-mail-address-alread/18154695#18154695) which appear to be exactly the same problem, but having name & email instead of name & titles.

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO title(value) VALUES ("Prof.");
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @title_id; 
    -- Instead of using user-defined variable, 
    -- you should be able to use the last_insert_id 
    -- equivalent from the host language MySQL driver.
INSERT INTO username(value) VALUES ("Sylvain");
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @username_id;
    -- Instead of using user-defined variable, 
    -- you should be able to use the last_insert_id 
    -- equivalent from the host language MySQL driver.

INSERT INTO account(username_id, email_id) VALUES (@username_id,@title_id); 
COMMIT;
```

See [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

---

A third solution would be to `SELECT` before doing you insert to see in the entry are already present. But personally I wouldn't push to the *check-before-set* approach at the very least, this will require an extra query which is mostly superfluous if you use correctly indexes.

Comment: I've read your linked post but I couldn't figure out if/how I can prevent the subselect in the last insert query with that? What I simple would like to do is this query:
INSERT INTO Person(nameId, titleId, age) VALUES ("Peter", "Astronaut", 33) but with a replace of the strings by the associated ids. If there's no id for a name it should be stored in the other tables before.

Comment: @user2170547 I've edited my answer to show you how to do that in SQL-only. The key idea is, since you will have two inserts you will be able to use `last_insert_id()` after each `INSERT` to obtain each entry's id (assuming `auto_increment` columns). Here I use MySQL user-defined variable. In real world, you will probably use plain variables from your host language.